# A probability transformation

Tags: probability, random-variables, transformation

Let $X,Y,Z$ be continuous random variables; $Z$ are independent of $X,Y$. Is the following transformation right ?
\begin{align}
P(X,Y \in (a,b),Y+Z \notin (a,b))&=\int_a^bP(X \in (a,b),y+Z \notin (a,b))f_Y(y)dy\\
&=\int_a^bP(X \in (a,b))P(Z \notin (a-y,b-y))f_Y(y)dy.
\end{align}
Thank you !

Comment: I just found, that
\begin{align}
P(X,Y \in (a,b),Y+Z \notin (a,b))&=\int_a^bP(X \in (a,b),y+Z \notin (a,b))f_Y(y)dy\\
&=\int_a^bP(X \in (a,b))P(Z \notin (a-y,b-y))f_Y(y)dy.\\
&=P(X \in (a,b))\int_a^bP(Z \notin (a-y,b-y))f_Y(y)dy\\
&=P(X \in (a,b))P(Y \in (a,b),Y+Z \notin (a,b)).
\end{align}
But this is wrong !

Comment: Sorry for my misleading comment (deleted now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line is right. The first line assumes independence of $X$ and $Y$ and is wrong otherwise. For instance, the left-hand side could be zero if $X$ and $Y$ never lie in $(a,b)$ at the same time, and yet the right-hand side could be non-zero.

Comment: Thanks, Joriki. Is there any way to modify it?

Comment: @mstar: You could write

$$
P(X,Y \in (a,b),Y+Z \notin (a,b))=\int_a^b\left(\int_a^bf_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\right)P(y+Z \notin (a,b))\,\mathrm dy\;.
$$